# Why is the mouse eating the cabinet shelves only

Tags: mice

I have a mouse that is getting in some way and only eats the edge of my freshly painted cabinet shelves.  There are lots of food in there that they usually eat like stuffing, bread crumbs etc, but they don’t bother any of the food only eats the outer edge of my cabinet shelf.

Comment: Are you quite sure it's a mouse? Carpenter ants or termites come to mind, and don't need as large a hole as a mouse to get in.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about home improvement within the scope defined in the [help center](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 5):

I asked my cat about this and she says she knows how mice operate and doesn't even need to see pictures of the damaged cabinets.

She says no doubt the mouse is entering the cabinet in a shelf that has no food on it, and is trying to chew his way from that shelf to another, where the stuffing, bread crumbs, etc. are stored.

If you leave the cabinet doors open overnight, the mouse will leave your shelves alone and confine his depredations to more traditional fare.

Of course, cats are supremely arrogant and often present mere guesses as qualified opinion, so she could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Mice, like most rodents, have front teeth that continuously grow. Even if there's no reason for them to chew on something they will instinctively still do so to prevent their teeth growing too large. If the mice have plenty of food the cabinet shelves may simply be an easily accessible piece of wood in a location that is safe for the mouse.